# ASP.NET MVC ajax server side validation without use of model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm using web services and I'm accessing it from a BaseController class. I would like to run server validation to check if the login is valid. That way I can throw an alert with the message if it's not valid. Alert is a client must. I'm kind of new to MVC, but know some basics.

I understand the security behind what I'm asking for. Login is the simplest example I could come up with.

Another Ex.

Say I have a contact form. I want to do server validation without refreshing the page. I get that I can post the form with AJAX. I need to return a list of errors and display them on the page. The validation will be done in a web service method called from the controller.

Comment: Are you asking about validation or authentication?

Comment: I'm getting back a custom object from a web service. Not the standard MVC stuff or model. So I can't use the "built in" methods. So think of it less as authentication, and more of getting a custom object back from a web service without leaving the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to pass your user name and password to a server controller and get result in client script, you can do like this

Have an action method in your Account Controller to validate your username password combination like this. You will return `Json` from the action method based on the validation you do in your method. We declare a class called "`JsonDataResult`" which you can use for the jSon communication. This class has two properties.a string property called "`Message`" where you can send a message("Success"/"Errors") and List of strings to store the error messages if any.

```
public class JsonDataResult
{
   public string Message { get;set;}
   public List<String> Items = new List<String>();
}
```

and here is my Action method looks like

```
  public ActionResult Logon(string userName,string password)
  {
       // check your username password and if there is its not valid, do this
        List<String> errors = new List<String>();
        errors.Add("username is not available");
        errors.Add("password is not nice!");

        var data = new JsonDataResult { Message = "Errors", Items = errors };
        return Json(data);
  }
```

You can Set the Value of Message as "Success" if the username and password is correct. You can skip adding the error messages also.

Now, from your client script, use jQuery post to post data to an Action Method and receive the jSon result and check the Message properties value. If it says "Errors", loop thru each errors and show it.

```
$(function () {
    $("form").submit(function () {
        $.post('@Url.Action("Logon","Account")', { userName: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password").val() }, function (data) {

            if (data.Message == "Errors") {
                $.each(data.Items, function (index) {
                    alert(data.Items[index]);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                // validation is successful.May be you want to redirect now ?
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have your web site invoke an AJAX POST with the credentials and invoke this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userEmail or whatever, true);
```

Then return a JSON result (not a View) and check for the result in your jQuery code on the website.

Comment: Do you have a good example of "Then return a JSON result (not a View) and check for the result in your jQuery code on the website."

Answer (score 1):

If you are using membership provider and need to validate user following can be used.

```
 bool isValidLogin = Membership.ValidateUser(UserName, Password);
```

OR try to get help from following

```
 bool isValidLogin = FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(UserName, Password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, though passing the password through an ajax request is probably not a good idea.

Your question is confusing, so here is the basic idea..

CS:

```
public AuthController
{
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CheckAuthentication(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            return Json(Membership.ValidateUser(UserName, Password));
        }
}
```

JS:

```
var authChecking = $.post("/Auth/CheckAuthentication", { UserName: username, Password: password });
authChecking.done(function(result) { if (!result) 
    {
        alert("Invalid");
        // or dialog or whatever.
    }
});
```

Comment: probably just pass the username and return whether it's a valid username, though again, don't think that's a security best practice to show users which usernames exist in the system

Comment: I understand your concerns. It's a closed system. Proof of concept prototype. Login may be handled differently later on but the concept is important for other forms. Login was the easiest example to explain.

Comment: Added example of some custom validation in a new answer, sorry if it's a bit messy

Answer (score 0):

I had to write some custom validation logic at some point for a lot of dynamic content that loosely had corresponding models, but based on selected options the validation was different. I'm just gonna copy and paste the code from my app and dumb it down, but you can follow the basic example. This is also for saving multiple forms in multiple tabs.. but works for one as well, but you can probably simplify it.. The JS is old and can be cleaned up a lot too with promises and distributed events, but that's a topic for a different day.

JS:

```
$("button#Save").on("click", function () {
            // checks if existing errors have been cleared before trying to submit again
        if ($(".ui-state-error, .ui-state-error-text", "#tabs").length) {
            alert("There are errors on the page. You must correct any errors before saving.");
        }
        else {
                // don't allow to submit twice.. again.. better ways to do this..
            if (!Saving) {
                Saving = true;
                            // show saving message overlay
                $('#CanvasLoading').html("Saving...<span>Loading</span>").show();
                //map data
                            // PASSES IN THE ID OF THE FORM
                var data = $("form.create-item-form", "#tabs").map(function () {
                    var $form = $(this);

                    return {
                        Name: $form.find(":input[name=Name]").val(),
                        FolderName: $form.find(":input[name=FolderName]").val(),
                        ItemName: $form.find(":input[name=ItemName]").val(),
                        ViewId: $form.find(":input[name=ViewId]").val(),
                        FormId: $form.attr("id")
                }).toArray();

                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: Routes.New.SaveAllPost,
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: { items: data },
                    success: function (resultJSON) {
                        var result = $.parseJSON(resultJSON);
                        if (result.Success) {
                                Saving = false;
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            $.each(result.Errors, function (i, item) {
     // loops through all items and applies class ui-state-error to inputs in the form with given id
                                var formId = item.FormId;
                                var propertyName = item.FieldName;
                                $.each(item.Errors, function (i, error) {
                                    var id = $("input[name=" + propertyName + "], select[name=" + propertyName + "]", "#" + formId).addClass("ui-state-error").parents("div.ui-tabs-panel:first").attr("id");
                                    $("#li-upload-" + id, "#tabs").addClass("ui-state-error");
                                });
                            });

                               // hide loading overlay
                            $('#CanvasLoading').hide();
                            Saving = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                alert("You have already started saving. Please wait for results to process.");
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
```

C#:

```
public class NewController : Controller
    {
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveAll(List<UploadViewModelDTO> items)
        {
            UploadItemValidationDTO validation = ValidateItems(items);
            if (validation.Success)
            {   
                // validated: do stuff

            }

            return Json(validation);
        }
}

private UploadItemValidationDTO ValidateItems(List<UploadViewModelDTO> items)
        {
            UploadItemValidationDTO validation = new UploadItemValidationDTO();

            // check for errors
            // if error add using following code
            // error has field name and id of form it came from
            validation.Errors.Add
            (
                new Error
                {
                    Errors = new List<string>() { "Folder is required" },
                    FieldName = "FolderName",
                    FormId = item.FormId
                }
            );          

            validation.Success = (validation.Errors.Count < 1);

            return validation;
        }

public class UploadItemValidation
    {
        public UploadItemValidation()
        {
            Errors = new List<Error>();
        }

        public bool Success {get;set;}
        public List<Error> Errors {get;set;}
    }

    public class Error
    {
        public string FormId {get;set;}
        public string FieldName {get;set;}
        public List<string> Errors {get;set;}
    }
```